# Why was ramjet fuel used as hydraulic fluid during Saturn V checkout?

Tags: fuel, saturn-v

> Fuel is also used within the engine as a lubricant and as a hydraulic
>   working fluid, though before launch, RJ-1 ramjet fuel is supplied from
>   the ground, it being more suited for this purpose.

https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap11fj/01launch.html

I can't seem to find any more background on why this was done. What properties made RP-1 unsuitable for ground use?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

What a fascinating question!

Turns out it's less flammable.

> Ground Supply Fluid—Because the flash point of RP-1 fuel, which
>   supplies the system in flight, is 110 to 139° F, it is classified as a
>   Class Ill flammable liquid, not suitable for ground operations. A
>   study was made to find substitute fluids with properties similar to
>   RP-1 that could be used in the laboratory and in ground operations.
>
> Such a fluid was found in RJ-1, a ramjet fuel. It has properties very
>   similar to RP-1, but a flashpoint ranging from 190 to 208° F. If
>   purchased with a specified flashpoint exceeding 200° F, it is not
>   classed as a flammable liquid by the National Code and would not have
>   the same stringent handling requirements of RP-1 fuels. Therefore, the
>   RJ-1 fuel can be used in the laboratories or in GSE with the same
>   precautions as taken with MIL-H-5606

GSE = Ground Support Equipment

[Source](https://www.hydraulicspneumatics.com/hydraulic-filters/hydraulic-controls-gimbaling-saturn-v-engines) - The December 1963 issue of *Hydraulics and Pneumatics* magazine

Comment: It seems ironic to use jet fuel because it's the *less* flammable option!

Comment: Only tangentially related, but apparently the US's nuclear ramjet program used the liquid sodium reactor coolant as hydraulic fluid. I can only imagine the lab safety manager's reaction to that one.

Comment: That makes sense. So it's roughly: "we use RP-1 as hydraulic fluid & lubricant in flight, because it means we don't need the complexity / weight / etc of having a separate tank / etc; as the system is designed to use RP-1 for lubricant / hydraulic fluid we need something similar on the ground; RJ-1 is 'close enough' while being somewhat less flammable."

Comment: @0xDBFB7 molten radioactive sodium as hydraulic fluid! *shudder* Of course if that was Project Pluto, that thing was Flying Armageddon anyway.

Comment: @OrganicMarble https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/839416.pdf one of the greatest table-of-contents I've ever seen in a paper, containing such terrific verbiage as "NaK Leak in Torque Motor after Servovalve Tests " and "Due
to the nature of the working fluid it is not practical to have interfaces
such as shaft seals directly exposed to an air environment."

Comment: @0xDBFB7 that is truly breathtaking, thanks for the link.